# Why doesn't the Demodulation FSK right?(with GNU Radio)

Tags: gnuradio

I have received a signal that the FSK modulation has been used according to the received spectrum.

I modulated it using GNU Radio, but it is strange that it does not start with Preamble. Does anyone know what is happening?

[image: Input Signal]

[image: Filtered signal]

[image: Spectrum Signal]

[image: Demodulation Signal]

Comment: why should it be starting with a preamble – it's slooow FSK, so if there's only one clear tone, you can be pretty sure you've found a transmission. Plus, no need for CSI – it's FSK.

Comment: (also, you're using the long long long deprecated-and-removed-from-current-GNU Radio WX GUI sinks; that's not a good idea, I'd recommend replacing with the QT GUI equivalents, which perform better)